# Get the selected value in a select - option Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, model, thymeleaf

Im trying to generate a search options and in myweb page the user choose the value that is looking for this is my html code:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><h2 align="left">Red Social: </h2></td>
            <td>
                <select th:field="*{redes}" name="redSoc">
                    <option th:each="r : ${redes}" th:value="${r.nombreRedSocial}"
                            th:text="${r.nombreRedSocial}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Buscar"/></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my controller code:

```
@GetMapping("/RedesSociales")
public String infoPorRedSocial(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "redSoc", required = false) String redSoc) {
    RedesSociales[] redes = redesService.obtenerTodasRedes();
    model.addAttribute("redes", redes);
    //model.addAttribute("grupo", null);
    System.out.println(redSoc);
    if (redSoc != null) {
        System.out.println(redSoc);
        model.addAttribute("info", infoService.obtenerTodosPorRedSocial(redSoc));
    }
    return "visual/reportes/ListarPorRedSocial";
}
```

Now as you can see im trying to get the value `redSoc` but im not sure how to the get this value from the selected option i tried several methods but didnt work.

EDIT:

I was using this code:

```
<form action="/RedesSociales" method="GET">

    <h2 align="left">Red Social: </h2>
    <input type="text" name="redSoc"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>

</form>
```

But this was not usefull because the option would be insert by the user and i wanted to made it more dynamic thats why now im using the current values stored in the database

Comment: already solve the problem <br> change mi code to this : `<table>
        <tr>
            <td><h2 align="left">Red Social: </h2></td>
            <td>
                <select  name="redSoc">
                    <option th:each="r : ${redes}" th:value="${r.nombreRedSocial}" th:text="${r.nombreRedSocial}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Buscar"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already solve the problem 
 Change my code to this :

```
<table> <tr> <td><h2 align="left">Red Social: </h2></td>
<td> <select name="redSoc"> <option th:each="r : ${redes}" th:value="${r.nombreRedSocial}" th:text="${r.nombreRedSocial}">
</option>
</select> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td><input type="submit" value="Buscar"/></td> </tr> </table>
```